# Rails 3, javascript is "not found" when running in production

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, assets, production, precompiled

I know it's related to assets, I do precompile the assets with

```
bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

But the browser gives me 404 for only one javascript (jquery.formalize.min.js) file, which is not generated for some reason. There is however the code for  jquery.formalize.min.js inside the precompiled application-xxxxxx.js.

I'm including it with:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "formalize/jquery.formalize.min", "main" %>
```

And the error message in Chrome looks like:

```
GET http://example.com/assets/jquery.formalize.min-724f21bf646762e539aa18c8db1d4d43.js 404 (Not Found)
```

Full path to the formalize js file is app/assets/formalize/jquery.formalize.min.js.

Of course, application.js is loading fine.

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "application", "main" %>
```

How do I load the formalize/jquery.formalize.min.js? Thanks.

Comment: I also found the plugin for [formalize](https://github.com/iain/formalize-rails), but now i'm only curious what I did wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Check your manifest file, which is app/assets/javascript/application.js by default.  The //= entries control what files get pre-processed into the combined file.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I added the formalize in there. re-ran bundle exec rake assets:precompile, still problematic. I'm going to re-read the manual :)

Answer (score 0):

This was due to another fact, that Rails above v3 doesn't have somtething like:

```
config.assets.precompile += %w( *.js *.css )
```

See [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10218740/rails-javascript-asset-missing-after-precompile) for more.