# js files from asset directory are not found on production machine

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have put all my javascript and css files in `/assets/javascripts` and `/assets/stylesheets` directories.

Example: `/assets/javascripts/common.js`

I load them in view file as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/common.js"></script>
```

I ran my rails app locally and it ran successfully. But on production machine, I getting the following error:

```
GET http://server-machine:port/javascripts/common.js 404 (Not Found)
```

Comment: Possible dupicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10177843/rails-3-javascript-is-not-found-when-running-in-production

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rails configuration is different between development and production. In production, assets are looked up from your public directory. Read up [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html) to know how to compile your assets to make it ready for production.

From the docs:

> In production, Rails precompiles these files to public/assets by
>   default. The precompiled copies are then served as static assets by
>   the web server. The files in app/assets are never served directly in
>   production.